# Merge data from one table to anoter with FK

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have to merge data from one table to another. Both of these tables have the same structure, something like this:

```
Id (PK*) | Name | ParetnId (FK to PK*, it's a tree)
```

What I'm trying to use:

- Plain *insert/update* - too long SQL, FK/PK issues (when I copy row with ParentId to not existing row)
- *merge* operator - much shorter, but the same issues

I know that some guys temporary turn constraints off, copy data and turn constraints on again. In my case I trying to avoid this. (Many threads writing to these tables, and I don't know how such tricks affected to transactions)

The problem is: how to merge (or just copy) records between such tables without turning constraints off.

Answer (score 0):

I could use some more information on the source table. I am assuming that it will not have the primary key column. If it also does not have the foreign key column, then I am assuming you can join to the target table to get the id (if so, you can eliminate the `AND EXISTS` clauses from below). The only trouble is that you will have to run this several times until there are no more inserts.

```
MERGE INTO Target AS T
  USING Source AS S
    ON S.Name = T.Name
  WHEN MATCHED AND EXISTS(
    SELECT *
      FROM Target
      WHERE Id = S.ParentID
    ) THEN
    UPDATE SET
      ParentId = S.ParentID
  WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND EXISTS(
    SELECT *
      FROM Target
      WHERE Id = S.ParentID
    ) THEN
    INSERT VALUES(
      S.Name,
      S.ParentID
      )
```